# thymeleaf inline calendar.format not parsing

Tags: calendar, format, inline, template-engine, thymeleaf

[[${#calendars.format(patient.dateOfBirth,'dd/MMM/yyyy')}]]

I can not begin to fathom why this isn't correct. The patient object exists, I am using other members of it without issue. the dateOfBirth member exists, I can display it unformatted without issue. The usage matches all examples I can find as far as I can tell. What am I missing?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong either. Have you tried debugging `org.thymeleaf.expression.Calendars` to see what happens?